# Performing self-assessment on highly specific questions

Tags: discussion, review, specific-question

**Self-Assessment Review**

The following post came up while I was doing the site self-assessment review:

> [Am I using "feature" correctly here?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/am-i-using-feature-correctly-here)

**First Reaction**

My first reaction is that this question is at least "Satisfactory", if not "Excellent". Someone asked a well written question about how to use the word "features" as it applies to people and received a correct, well written answer.

Helping users identify and correct usage errors like this one seems to be one of the reasons this site exists.

**Self-Assessment Criteria**

Here's my interpretation of how the question rates against the self-assessment criteria:

1. *Question:* Well-written.
2. *Answer:* Clear, comprehensive answer, though I would have pointed out that the sentence should have used the word "chances" instead of "changes".
3. *Comparison with other resources:* This question is very specific. It's not clear where else you'd look for an answer to this question.
4. *Search results:* Again, this question is very specific. It's not clear anyone else would want to search for it. Having said that, I couldn't find it in the first few pages of Google results after a few tries.
5. *Generally useful:* It's not clear anyone else would make this same exact usage mistake.

**My Questions**

1. How would you rate the above post?
2. How should we balance the criteria when it comes to rating these highly specific posts?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I will say that this is pretty much exactly what confuses me when doing the self-assessments. (What to do when the question meets one criterion but not another, is googleability always valid, etc.) Maybe someone else will have some insight!

Comment: We should not be overthinking this. The idea behind the review is not for every single datapoint to be 100% precisely and objectively right. (Arguably there can be no such thing no matter how you try.) The idea is to get a whole number of datapoints and then look at the big picture they add up to. Hive mind, law of large numbers, that kind of thing. Meanwhile, your assessment is *your* assessment. So when in doubt, err on the side of — whatever you yourself wish to err on the side of in that moment.

Comment: @ЯegDwight Thank you... That helps.